Pynput for testing if ctrl, shift or alt are pressed
Is there a way in Pynput to test if ctrl, shift or alt are pressed in the òn_pressed or on_release handler?

[If we take reference of the pynput docs here is what we can do :-
def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.ctrl:
        print("Ctrl key pressed")
    elif key == keyboard.Key.shift:
        print("Shift key pressed")
    elif key == keyboard.Key.alt:
        print("Alt key pressed")
def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False
# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

or  if you wish you can even store the keys in a dictionary to iterate through like this:-
COMBINATION = {keyboard.Key.ctrl, keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.Key.alt}
] 1
In the above provided examples we have used the pynput.keyboard.Listener for to check if ctrl, shift or alt are pressed in the òn_pressed or on_release handler
Another way of doing so is by using pynput.keyboard.Controller
[Here is what we can do :-

alt_pressed
Whether any alt key is pressed.

Please note that this reflects only the internal state of this controller. See modifiers for more information.

ctrl_pressed
Whether any ctrl key is pressed.

Please note that this reflects only the internal state of this controller. See modifiers for more information.

shift_pressed
Whether any shift key is pressed, or caps lock is toggled.

Please note that this reflects only the internal state of this controller. See modifiers for more information.


Hence we can simply utilize these functions as:-
kb = keyboard.Controller()
if kb.ctrl_pressed:
    print("Ctrl key is pressed")
if kb.shift_pressed:
    print("Shift key is pressed")
if kb.alt_pressed:
    print("Alt key is pressed")
print(f"Key pressed: {key.char}")

]2
